# Linux "dump(8)" command

Tags: linux, linux-mint, backup

I intend to use dump(8) for backing up a Mint disk.
Here is the documentation about it: http://linux.die.net/man/8/dump

However—is it deprecated? (The documentation does not say it works with ext4).
Is it a Debian & co (Ubuntu, mint) solution ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason you want to use dump?

For file-level backup, `tar` is far more common. You can also do "incremental" backups [using the "-N" option](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/after.html#after). Also, you can use data compression on-the-fly using algorithms like gzip, bzip2 or lzma/xz.
Directly storing to magnetic tapes is still supported these days ;)

For raw/low-level backups of partitions, you can use `dd`, `ddrescue` or `pv` on the device file itself.

Comment: Probably because dump and restore were mentioned in a [related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211287/backup-system-image) The manpage says that they work with ext2 and ext3, so I guess it's okay for these filesystems, of course depending on what the actual goal is.

Comment: goal is to backup, first. Later, to clone disk to children...

Comment: Ah right, didn't check OP-posts on related questions. @ArchiT3K: You can perfectly use tar to do a complete backup of an installed linux-system and then use a bootable CD/USB drive to restore that installation to any partition. The only thing you have to do after extracting the archive is to re-install or update your bootloader. And since tar is file-system-independant, you can also backup a system installed on an ext4 file-system and restore that to a btrfs-formatted partition.

Comment: Thanks @Jannis, can I avoid upadatubg the bootloader, by cloning it too ? noob noob noob

Comment: SInce the bootloader is not part of or stored in a file system, this is not possible using methods such as tar or dump.
You can, however, do a binary backup of the complete drive (including the bootloader) and then clone that to your children/slaves. However, this will erase all existing partitions on the target.

Comment: (1) `dump` can handle `ext4` filesystems just fine (at least recent versions do); (2) it isn't deprecated; (3) it doesn't have the limitations of `tar` / `pax` and `cpio` WRT file lengths; (4) it handles hard links without running out of RAM, unlike `rsync`; (5) it can handle incremental backups and doesn't save empty space, unlike `dd`.

Comment: Thanks to all. I have dumped my drive, ext4, on a ext4 usb drive. Terminal says it s ok.But I dont see anything on the usb drive, is it normal ? @ lcd047 : thanks, perfect answer to me.

Comment: GNU tar is extremely unreliable with incremental restores. It cannot restore incrementals in case that there are more than simple diffs in the dump. This is a result of the arhive format used by GNU tar that does not handle the needed meta data.